# string object behavior in python

Tags: python, string

curious to know the reason for following

```
x='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 
y='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
x is y
#output : True
```

```
x='a'*21 
y='a'*21
x is y
#output : False
```

Q1: since string interning is done for string literals then why not for 'a'*21 ? is it not a string literal?
Q2: is it because expression 'a'*21 is evaluated at run-time and interning is done at runtime?

#

```
s1 = "strin"
s2 = "string"
s1+"g" is s2

# output : False 
# Explaination : Above code involves a run-time concatenation, the result of which is not automatically interned

Q3: How to know if an expression is going to be evaluated at run-time or compile time?
```

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, so what exactly do you mean by "evaluated at (...) compile time?"

Comment: In CPython, conditions are never evaluated "at compiled time".  Not sure what language you're coming from, but any ideas about smart compilers and optimizing compilers go out the window with Python.  CPython's compile stage essentially serves to translate the human readable code verbatim to python bytecode

Comment: python's interning details are undocumented implementation details, they can easily change, just don't worry about them, in the rare cases you need to enrforce interning, you can use `sys.intern` in py3

Answer (score 0):

`is` will return True if two variables point to **the same object**, `==` will return True if the objects referred to by the variables **are equal**. If you try:

```
s1 = "strin"
s2 = "string"
s1+"g" == s2
# True

x='a'*21 
y='a'*21
x == y
True
```

In your first case, Python was intelligent enough to use one single object to refer to the literal string you described twice. This is generally not the case.